Exponeintal of symmetric triangular matrix
I want to know the exponeintal of given $n \times n$ symmetirc real tridiagonal matrix ${\bf K}_n$, which is defined as
$${\bf K}_n=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
a & 0 & a & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & a & 0 & a & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & a & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & a & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $a$ is given real number. The exponential of the matrix ${\bf K}_n$ is defined as
$$\exp{[{\bf K}_n}] \equiv \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{{\bf K}_n^m}{m!} = {\bf I} + {\bf K}_n +\frac{{\bf K}^2_n}{2!} + \frac{{\bf K}^3_n}{3!} + \dots.
$$
I used Mathematica 12 and it seems that there is a closed form of the matrix $\exp{[{\bf K}_n}]$. But I could not find rule for general natural number $n$. How can I obtain a general expression for $\exp{[{\bf K}_n}]$ in closed form?
$$\exp{[{\bf K}_2}]=\begin{bmatrix}
1+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^4}{24}+\dots & a+\frac{a^3}{6}+\frac{a^5}{120}+\dots \\
a+\frac{a^3}{6}+\frac{a^5}{120}+\dots & 1+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^4}{24}+\dots \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\exp{[{\bf K}_3}]=\begin{bmatrix}
1+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^4}{12}+\dots & a+\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{a^5}{30}+\dots & \frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^4}{12} \dots  \\
a+\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{a^5}{30}+\dots & 1+a^2+\frac{a^4}{6}+\dots & a + \frac{a^3}{3} + \frac{a^5}{30} \dots \\ 
\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^4}{12}+\dots & a+\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{a^5}{30} \dots & 1 + \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{a^4}{12} \dots \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\exp{[{\bf K}_4}]=\begin{bmatrix}
1+\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^4}{12} \dots & a + \frac{a^3}{3} + \frac{a^5}{24} \dots & \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{a^4}{8} \dots & \frac{a^3}{6} + \frac{a^5}{40}\dots \\ 
a + \frac{a^3}{3} + \frac{a^5}{24} \dots & 1 + a^2 + \frac{5a^4}{24}\dots & a + \frac{a^3}{2} + \frac{a^5}{15} \dots& \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{a^4}{8}\dots \\
\frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{a^4}{8} \dots& a + \frac{a^3}{2} + \frac{a^5}{15} \dots& 1 + a^2 + \frac{5a^4}{24}\dots & a + \frac{a^3}{3} + \frac{a^5}{24}\dots \\
\frac{a^3}{6} + \frac{a^5}{40} \dots & \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{a^4}{8} \dots & a + \frac{a^3}{3} + \frac{a^5}{24} \dots & 1 + \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{a^4}{12} \dots \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Just in case, this is the used code for mathematica:
K = {
 {0, a, 0, 0},
 {a, 0, a, 0},
 {0, a, 0, a},
 {0, 0, a, 0}
}
   IdentityMatrix[4] + MatrixPower[K, 1] + MatrixPower[K, 2]/2! + 
   MatrixPower[K, 3]/3! + MatrixPower[K, 4]/4! + 
   MatrixPower[K, 5]/5! // MatrixForm


Given that your matrix is symmetric and real (we can factor by a), it can be diagonalized. Once diagonalized it'll be much easier to compute the exponential: $$\exp(P^T diag(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)P)=P^Tdiag(\exp(\lambda_1), \cdots, \exp(\lambda_n))P$$ with $P$ orthogonal. Moreover, it's a Toeplitz matrix, its eigenvalues are known: $$\lambda_{k}=2|a|\cos\left[\frac{k\pi}{(n+1)}\right], \quad k=1\cdots n.$$

Thank you. The eigenvalues ${\bf P}$ also has a closed form. So, we can find the closed form of $\exp{ [{\bf K}_n] }$ using them.
